# keeping an activity just for production Elixir Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am doing as written below in my project. But I only want to run it in Production mode, not in development mode, for this, I tried with `Mix.env` and it worked locally by giving me `:dev` or `:prod` but It didn't work on online API. It got an error as there is nothing like env.

I want to make it just for production with some kind of pattern matching function

```
  Task.start(fn ->
    if user |> Intercom.get_user |> intercom_user? do
      Logger.info "User '#{user.username}' already present at Intercom."
    else
      Intercom.create_user(user, user_agent, requester_ip)
    end
  end)
```

any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll have to set a config for this in the `config/*.exs` files as `Mix` is usually not included in production releases. You could just store the env value or a more meaningful name like `:create_intercom_user`.

In `config/dev.exs` and `config/test.exs`:

```
config :my_app, :create_intercom_user, false
```

In `config/prod.exs`:

```
config :my_app, :create_intercom_user, true
```

and then in your code:

```
if Application.get_env(:my_app, :create_intercom_user) do
  Task.start(fn -> ... end)
end
```

or:

In `config/config.exs`:

```
config :my_app, :mix_env, Mix.env
```

and in your code:

```
if Application.get_env(:my_app, :mix_env) == :prod do
  Task.start(fn -> ... end)
end
```

(Replace `:my_app` with your app's name.)